# Pairgrid use upper triangle for correlations, access "full data"

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a dataset that I want to plot, and set the `hue` to a categorical variable, and put that into the lower triangle of a seaborn PairGrid. On the upper triangle, I want to annotate the correlation of the pairs of variables, but NOT in a "per class" fashion.

To explain what I mean with a sample dataset, we can use the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

def reg_coef(x,y,label=None,color=None,**kwargs):
    ax = plt.gca()
    r,p = pearsonr(x,y)
    ax.annotate('r = {:.2f}'.format(r), xy=(0.5,0.5), xycoords='axes fraction', ha='center')
    ax.set_axis_off()

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
g.map_upper(reg_coef)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot, alpha=0.3)
plt.show()

g = sns.PairGrid(iris, hue='species')
g.map_upper(reg_coef)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot, alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

That code will generate two images, the first one, has the upper triangle that I want (the Pearson correlation between each pair of variables), and the second image has the lower triangle that I want (the scatter plots and density estimations by class).

[image]

See how in the second image, because a portion of the data is passed to `reg_coef`, the annotations are printed on top of one another. I'd like to have the upper triangle from the first figure in the second one.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking the [relevant source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/0f538fb40ad04174a9298f9403783308f9bbb370/seaborn/axisgrid.py#L1464), I'm answering my own question.

If the function `func` you pass to the `map` function explicitly sets `hue` as a keyword, it indicates `PairPlot` that the hue separation will be handled by `func`, and not by `PairPlot`. Therefore, to achieve the desired output in my example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

# the only difference is that I add a hue keyword, even if I ignore it. 
def reg_coef(x,y,label=None,color=None,hue=None,**kwargs):
    ax = plt.gca()
    r,p = pearsonr(x,y)
    ax.annotate('r = {:.2f}'.format(r), xy=(0.5,0.5), xycoords='axes fraction', ha='center')
    ax.set_axis_off()

g = sns.PairGrid(iris, hue='species')
g.map_upper(reg_coef, hue=None)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot, alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image]